# Discord.py music bot commands not working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am currently trying to make a Music Bot that uses Youtube for my discord server since Groovy and Rhythm have been taken down. When I run the code for the bot I get no errors at all but when I try and do the commands nothing happens. Would be amazing if someone could help me out.
I have 2 files for this: main.py and music.py.

Code for main.py:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import music 

cogs = [music]

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())

for i in range(len(cogs)):
  cogs[i].setup(client)


client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
  print('Bot Activated')



client.run("insert token here")`
```

Code for music.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import youtube_dl

class music(commands.Cog):
  def __init__(self, client):
    self.client = client
  
  @commands.command()
  async def join(self,ctx):
    if ctx.author.voice is None:
      await ctx.send("Join a Voice Channel First!")
    voice_channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    if ctx.voice_client is None:
      await voice_channel.connect()
    else:
      await voice_channel.move_to(voice_channel)
  @commands.command()
  async def disconnect(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

  @commands.command()
  async def play(self,ctx,url):
    ctx.voice_client.stop()
    FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5', 'options': '-vn'}
    YDL_OPTIONS = {'format':"bestaudio"}
    vc = ctx.voice_client
    
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
      info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
      url2 = info['formats'][0]['url']
      source = await discord.FFmpegOpusaudio.from_probe(url2, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS)
      vc.play(source)

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.resume()
    await ctx.send("Resume")

  @commands.command()
  async def pause(self,ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.pause()
    await ctx.send("Paused")

def setup(client):
  client.add_cog(music(client))
```

Comment: You use `client = discord.Client()` AND `client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='?', intents = discord.Intents.all())`. Simply remove `client = discord.Client()` and try again.